# Max Characters VB.Net Control

Tags: vb.net, textbox, character

I'd like to know which VB.net control has more characters. To explain better:
I have a file with 1 million ca characters, well I want to insert all content in a VB.net control, either textbox, richtextbox or labels.

If a control with that huge capacity doesn't exist, is there any way I can set limit max 1 million and display them anyway (e.g. in a textbox)?

Much appreciated your help!

Comment: You need this for webform or windows form?

Comment: for windows forms.. i think max richtextbox limit is 65535

Comment: No, that was 25 years ago.  You can stuff a big fat novel like War & Peace in a RichTextBox.  The practical limit is your user's patience, a whole lot less than the real limit.

Comment: thank you, i understand. though if I search for a word inside the richtextbox using `Text.Contains()`method, it doesn't find it.. using a file with less characters (100000) it works with the same word. what can it be? btw I create the richtextbox at runtime, can it make difference? thanks again.

Comment: oh sorry found mistake: I was searching for an uppercase word on the bigger file but all were lowercase.. btw why is case-sensitive? O.o

Answer (score 2):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> When this property is set to 0, the maximum length of the text that
>   can be entered in the control is limited only by available memory.